# Environment Variables not detected in Gatsby Build

Tags: build, environment-variables, gatsby, production

My env api are able to detect on development, but not able to on production (build).

[image: I've arranged the .env files this way]

This is how my code looks like

[image: app.js code]

And I've added this in the gatsby-config after installing

[image: env plugin]

This is the error I get when typing 'gatsby build' :

[image: gatsby build error]

I've also tried all other solutions I've found to this similar issue but nothing works.

- Added environment settings in Gatsby Cloud
- Changing location of the Weather.js file